# Parsing CSV files in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex, csv

I am playing a video game that exports statistics into a CSV file.

http://pastebin.com/FPzJ3Qz7

Row 5 are my headers/tables.

I have a PHP/MySQL database that stores the data...

My issue is, every time I need to **delete the first 4 lines**, and all the ones **after line 498**. Because I am only interested in the data in between.

The line numbers can change every time.

I can use Regex to match the part I need, but when I use file_get_contents, it removes the new lines, and makes one big string.

Ultimately my goal is, upload CSV to web server, run cron to load PHP script, parse out the CSV, then run SQL statements to read CSV and update/insert into the database.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: In addition to @RiggsFolly's comment, this issue has been addressed a couple of times - [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) or [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will be good starting points (and would have revealed themselves by simply googling...)

Comment: If you're using cron to run this task, you don't even need to use PHP.  Use `head` and `tail` to extract the portion of the file you need, then load it using `mysql`'s `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just wanted ideas on achieving it, not the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `file()` instead of `file_get_contents()`, you'll get an array with a value per each line of your code. From there onward, you could use `array_search()` to find where your delimiters are located, and then use `array_splice()` to land with the relevant portion of the data.

However, since you're already `preg_match()`ing the bulk and extracting the relevant portion, this is real easy. `$entries = explode("\n", $bulk);` will give you an array with a line of data on each.

Then you can iterate over your array and e.g. use `explode(',', $entryline)` to parse each data-string to an array. There's also `str_getcsv()`, but in your case you'll have to tick off the default enclosure, since your data is unenclosed. Then plug that into matching fields in your database.

MySQL can also directly import CSV data with something like: `LOAD DATA INFILE '/scores.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 4 LINES;` -- though you'd have to somehow get rid of the chunk in the end, this is for uniform CSV data.

*[If you have working code where you're trying to solve this, add it to your question for more help.]*

Comment: Hey there, best comment so far... Here is my current code, based on what you've said. array_search is giving me some issues though. [link](http://pastebin.com/VRTnb4H0)

Comment: You have a space after your delimiter there on the unfortunate line 13. If you get rid of it, `array_search` gives you `int(531)` instead. ;) BTW you don't need to do `$stats2 = array_slice($stats, 4);`, you can simply `$stats = array_slice($stats, 4);` or otherwise use `array_splice`, saving every version of the data in a different variable eats up memory.

Comment: Hmm, I removed the space, and it still wont display anything? And thanks for the tip on the $stats / $stats2

Comment: I ran the code you posted above and `array_search` returned index 531 after I trimmed the space at the end of your ---- delimiter. Make sure you search for the exact right thing. Should work.

Comment: Yeah, thats strange. When I var_dump the $key it says bool(false)

Comment: If your line 13 is `$val = "--------------------------------------------------------------";` without the trailing space, and your data is exactly what you posted, there's no obvious reason it shouldn't work. Do double-check both.

Comment: Interesting, still not working. I even echo'd out the index ($stats[531]) and it gave me: --------------------------------------------------------------. I'll accept your answer, because it's something obviously wrong on my end. Even pregmatch works.

Comment: Heckle yourself and try `$val = $stats[531]; array_search($val, $stats);`. If even that fails, something is funny indeed. Best of luck and cheers for the click. ... oh yes. You could also `explode` the string stash of data by your delimiter. That'd make the third chunk your relevant slice.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading all the file (that uses memory for nothing), you can read the file line by line (as a stream) and build a generator function that returns the records you are interested by one by one. In this way you don't need to delete, you only need to use conditions and to select what you want. Example:

```
function getLineFromFileHandler($fh, $headers = false) {
    // initializations
    $sectionSeparator = str_repeat('-', 62);
    $newline = "\r\n";
    $sectionSeparatorNL = $sectionSeparator . $newline;
    $rowSeparatorNL = ',' . $newline;

    // skip title/subtitle (feel free to add a param to yield them)
    $title = stream_get_line($fh, 4096, $sectionSeparatorNL);
    $subtitle = stream_get_line($fh, 4096, $sectionSeparatorNL);

    // get the field names
    $fieldNamesLine = stream_get_line($fh, 4096, $rowSeparatorNL);

    // return the records
    if ($headers) {
       $fieldNames = array_map('trim', explode(',', $fieldNamesLine));

       while (($line = stream_get_line($fh, 4096, $rowSeparatorNL)) !== false &&
              strpos($line, $sectionSeparator) === false)
           yield array_combine($fieldNames, explode(',', $line));
    } else {
       while (($line = stream_get_line($fh, 4096, $rowSeparatorNL)) !== false &&
              strpos($line, $sectionSeparator) === false)
           yield explode(',', $line);
    }
}

$fh = fopen('csv.txt', 'r');

foreach(getLineFromFileHandler($fh, true) as $record)
    print_r($record);

fclose($fh);
```

This example displays each record as an associative array with the field name as key. As you can see you can remove the second parameter of the generator function to obtain an indexed array. Feel free to choose the most convenient way to insert records into your database (one by one, by blocks, or all in one shot).

Comment: This would be the way to go for sure if we're dealing with one of those massive dumps. However it's probably not very consequential memory-wise if it's a few dozen KB file tops. Of course, know your future data and be set to scale up. Not doing what you do is a killer if you're loading in megabytes worth of CSV at once, 1 MB raw data is easily 10x in RAM, little integers in particular add to the array's memory-bulk.

Answer (score 0):

Try the PHP function `file()`, which gets a file as an array -- each line is an element in the array. Then you can loop through the lines starting and ending wherever you need to.

Comment: [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) would come in handy as well.